# How to see changelogs for a particular module in kernel

Tags: linux, git, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I want to know how to see the changelogs or commit messages for a module in the kernel. Actually i modified virtio_net in kernel2.6.26. Now the virtio_net in 2.6.34 seems to be lot different from the one in 2.6.26. There should be some git commit messages or changelogs for the different versions of virtio_net. I want to know the progressive difference in features for the module in 2.6.26 and 2.6.34. How to do that? Thank you...

Thanks,
Bala

Comment: maybe superuser.com can help you better.

Comment: There's a lot of questions on git already in SO, which is what this amounts to, so I don't see why this won't be ontopic too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, install git and clone the kernel tree:

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git
```

Now you can use git log on an file(s) or directory.

```
git log drivers/net/virtio_net.c
```